# React-router doesnt work after upgrading from 0.13 to 2.8.1

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I upgraded my react-router from version 0.13 to 2.8.1, Then it give an error saying that "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react'
import Router from 'react-router'

import App from './components/app';
import Main from './components/main';
import CreateOrganization from './components/create-organization';
import ManageUsers from './components/manage-users';
import FldList from './components/fld-list';
import FldView from './components/fld-view';
import WeighIn from './components/weigh-in';
import MatchFlds from './components/match-flds';
import NotFound from './components/not-found';

var { Route, DefaultRoute, NotFoundRoute } = Router;

var routes = (
    <Route handler={App}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Main} />
        <Route name="CreateOrganization" path="create-organization" handler={CreateOrganization}></Route>
        <Route name="manageUsers" path="manage-users" handler={ManageUsers}></Route>
        <Route name="fldList" path="fld-list" handler={FldList}></Route>
        <Route name="fldView" path="fld-view/:fldId" handler={FldView}></Route>
        <Route name="weighIn" path="weigh-in" handler={WeighIn}></Route>
        <Route name="matchFlds" path="match-flds" handler={MatchFlds}></Route>
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
});
```

What should I do here to resolve this error?

Comment: look through the new API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain changes have happened to the API and some components have been replaced or become deprecated. Please have a look at the [**API here**](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) and read the [**upgrade guide here**](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/d28036b97e1e991b2cf502a108673303ac5e0149/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md).

Your route should work if you make the following changes:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Main} />
  <Route name="CreateOrganization" path="create-organization" component={CreateOrganization}></Route>
  <Route name="manageUsers" path="manage-users" component={ManageUsers}></Route>
  <Route name="fldList" path="fld-list" component={FldList}></Route>
  <Route name="fldView" path="fld-view/:fldId" component={FldView}></Route>
  <Route name="weighIn" path="weigh-in" component={WeighIn}></Route>
  <Route name="matchFlds" path="match-flds" component={MatchFlds}></Route>
  <Route path="**" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

You also need to replace this:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
});
```

with:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
let history = createBrowserHistory()
render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, el)
```

---

Here's a brief list of changes (not all) to take note of:

- The `handler` property is now called `component`
- The `<DefaultRoute>` component is now called `<IndexRoute>`
- The `<NotFoundRoute>` component is now deprecated. Use a "catch-all" pattern. Either `*` or `**` (non-greedy vs greedy - read the docs).

Answer (score 5):

***This answer has been tested on React Router ver 2.7.0***

Version 2 of React Router introduced the concepts of `IndexRoute`, `browserHistory`.

The rough outline of how you could configure your routes is below. Please review the official docs to adjust it to your use case.

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <IndexRoute component={Main} />
        <Route path="create-organization" component={CreateOrganization} />
        <Route path="manage-users" component={ManageUsers} />
        <Route path="fld-list" component={FldList} />
        <Route path="fld-view/:fldId" component={FldView} />
        <Route path="weigh-in" component={WeighIn} />
        <Route path="match-flds" component={MatchFlds} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
);

React.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
);

// Also, in newer versions of React you can use ReactDOM for mounting your app.
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
//ReactDOM.render(
//  routes,
//  document.getElementById('react-container')
//);
```

Comment: Thanks Piotr. Is that version 4.0.0 style? I think it has changed quite a bit. I might have to downgrade by upgrade. ;) Have to update my code above as we do not have 'react-container' I think it was copy pasted from the project's documentation. We actually have Router.run(routes,   React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('content'));

Comment: Hi :) the answer is based on React Router 2.7.0 spec and it's unfortunately no longer valid for React Router 4.0.0. I hope your find a good solution.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. I have managed to downgrade to Router 3.x and got that part working, not to fix the 1000+ errors because of 0.13 React codebase and all the changes React API and 50+ third party projects have changed in 2 years and not backwards compatible. :D Looks like a 3 month project for us to finish the full upgrade. so have to work on a separate branch while doing all the other new features, upgrades and fixes to our own app code base. Fun stuff. Wish it was all backwards compatible to save us this trouble.